# I want to work 1/3 of screen with pygame but how?

Tags: pygame

I 'm working with pygame. I have a background picture(size=600, 600) and I want to give blur effect to picture but not full picture. I want to give blur effect only 1/3 picture (size=600, 200). I want  2/3 of picture not blur. How can I do this? Not: I know blur effect, I only want to learn split the screen ?

Comment: you could cut the background surface into 2 parts and blur the smaller one

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to blur the bottom third.  You will have to do something similar to the following:

```
#background is the background picture
blurred=pygame.Surface((600, 200))
temprect=background.get_rect()
temprect.top=400
blurred.blit(background, temprect)
#blur "blurred" here
temprect=blurred.get_rect()
temprect.top=400
background.blit(blurred, temprect)
```

This should work, but let me know if it doesn't.